# How to set values for Progressbar in Android

Tags: android

In my application I should set **2 value** for `linear progressbar`. 
**Such as below image:** 
[image]

I write below **codes in XML:**

```
<com.google.android.material.progressindicator.LinearProgressIndicator
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:max="150"
    android:rotation="180"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_10mdp"
    app:indicatorColor="@color/mystic"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/rightSectionLay"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/arrowImg"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:trackColor="@color/whileSmoke"
    app:trackCornerRadius="@dimen/_10mdp"
    app:trackThickness="@dimen/_3mdp" />
```

In `LinearProgressIndicator` just can **one value**, but in above image `progressbar` has **2 values**.
One of values fill from **center to right** and another value fill from **center to left**!

I searched in **Google** and **AndroidArsenal** but not found any solution or library!

How can I use `progressbar` with this option?

Comment: You can also use 2 progress bars and place them back-to-back, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution using 2 progress bars, aligned back-to-back with each other. One of them is scaled -1 for the X axis, making it go from right to left.

```xml
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">

        
    <com.google.android.material.progressindicator.LinearProgressIndicator
        android:id="@+id/progressBarLeft"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:progress="50"
        android:scaleX="-1"
     />

        
    <com.google.android.material.progressindicator.LinearProgressIndicator
        android:id="@+id/progressBarRight"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:progress="50"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, I can use such as your solution. but I think it's not good way!

Comment: I think it is a simple straight-forward solution. If it was encapsulated inside a custom view you wouldn't event know about this being 2 progress bars..